# CSS Sprite Active State

Tags: css, menu, sprite

Hi I have looked at other examples on here with similar problems and none of the solutions seem to work for me. I have a CSS sprite image with two images overlapping. The top image is for the link state and the bottom image is for :hover and :active. :hover works but the :active state does not display. Any information would be greatly appreciated!

```
CSS:
.menu {
    width: 855px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
.menu ul {
list-style-type: none;
}
.menu ul li {
    float: left;
    background-color:#234C94;
}
.menu ul li a {
    display: block;
    height: 52px;
    width: 122px;
    background-color: #27589B;
    text-indent: -9999px;
}    
.menu ul li a.welcome {
    background-image: url(IMG/IMAGE.png)
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0px 0px;
}   
.menu ul li a.welcome:hover {
    background-image: url(IMG/IMAGE.png)
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0px -52px;
} 
.menu ul li a.welcome:active {
    background-image: url(IMG/IMAGE.png)
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0px -52px;
```

HTML:

```
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
   <li><a href="Counselor.html" class="welcome">Item 1</a></li>
   <li class="academics"><a href="Academics.html" class="academic">Item 2</a></li>
   <li><a href="Athletics.html" class="athletic">Item 3</a></li>
   <li><a href="ClubsORGs.html" class="club">Item 4</a></li>
   <li><a href="ResidentialLife.html" class="life">Item 5</a></li>
   <li><a href="Education.html" class="exp">Item 6</a></li>
   <li><a href="Map.html" class="map">Item 7</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Two things:
First, when you use :hover and :active and other such things, the base style is taken, so you do not need to re-declare the `background-image` and `background-repeat` styles, once will do.

Secondly, the reason :hover and :active do not differ is because your `background-position` is the same on both. I assume that is a careless error and you are probably going to face-palm when you realize this :)

Good Luck!

Comment: the first bar in the sprite is white and the second bar is yellow. I want the hover to be yellow and the active to be yellow once the user selects. For some reason the hover works but not the active

Comment: Well, what shows up on the :active state? does it go back to normal state's image ? Please say what is happening and I can guide you in the right direction.

Comment: My code is similar to LG's. If I click on an image, the **active** state shows only while the mouse button is being held down - not if that page is loaded. Perhaps my understanding of **active** (the term) is incorrect. How do I set the current page to be the "active" page?

Comment: Yes, your understanding of :active is incorrect. active applies only when you are moused down on a link. Current page to active page requires javascript.